# Location route not matching

Tags: nginx

I have a location which simply for some reason isn't triggering. I've tried the routes in all sorts of different orders, and still it doesn't work. When a user comes along and requests /_hostmanager/ it should trigger, but instead it gets the index.php page from the route.

The server config file is:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name _;
    listen 80;

    # Logging
    error_log /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log;

    # Route standard requests
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    # Proxy Hostmanager
    location /_hostmanager/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8999/;
    }

    # Include PHP
    location ~ \.php {

        # CGI Configuration
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;

        # Zero-day exploit defense
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;

        # Use socket for connection
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    }

    # Cache control
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml)$ {
        log_not_found off;
        expires 360d;
    }

    # Disable hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Can anyone spot what my (probably stupid!) error is?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I worked it out! For some reason using the reload command on nginx wasn't working. stopped and started and voila!